# HOW TO HANDLE ERROR SOAPEXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED IN C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to consume my webservice to my windows application. My webService 
return datatable. Error occurs in my windows application.

here's my code:

this is my code in Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataTable searchCom(string compCode)
       {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALPC\\SQLEXPRESS1; Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectPress", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compCode;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(dt); 
            return dt;
       }
```

This is my code in Windows Application Form:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = service.searchCom(textBox1.Text);
            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = row["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = row["balance"].ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = row["maintBalance"].ToString();
                    textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
                    button1.Visible = false;
                    Back.Visible = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Share the error.

Comment: SoapException was unhandled.

Comment: Its your webservice which is giving error, have you added the reference correctly if yes then try to update the reference and run the project again.

Comment: already done that, I've been debugging several times but it always error "SOAPEXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try changing my web-service DataTable to DataSet and it works perfectly.
just answering my own problem :P

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataSet searchCom(string compCode)
       {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALPC\\SQLEXPRESS1; Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;");
            conn.Open();
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectPress", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compCode;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(dt); 
            return dt;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle exception at web service level.

```
[WebMethod]
       public DataTable searchCom(string compCode)
       {
          try
            {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALPC\\SQLEXPRESS1; Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectPress", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compCode;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(dt); 
            return dt;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
             throw new SoapException("Exception :",   
             SoapException.ServerFaultCode, "SoapException", ex);
           }
       }
```

Then catch the exception at consumer end

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         try
            {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = service.searchCom(textBox1.Text);
            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = row["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = row["balance"].ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = row["maintBalance"].ToString();
                    textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
                    button1.Visible = false;
                    Back.Visible = true;
                }
            }
           }
         catch (SoapException ex)
         {
            if(ex.Actor == "SoapException")
              //Do something
         }    
        }
```

Comment: i try this and it works but web-services doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the WebService to run as NTLM?

WebServices, by default, run as Anonymous in IIS.  But you've got your SQL Connection using Integrated security (aka, the currently logged in user).  Have you set your web service to run using NTLM or something?  Because unless you go out of your way during your service setup and connection, you're going to get an exception because it can't connect into the SQL database as the default IIS user.

Comment: i have no problem connecting to SQL, cuz the code i share can return datatable it just that error occurs after executing the web services.